# Why is my S3 bucket policy denying cross account access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket located in account A.

This bucket is shared with account B using *ACL grant* with account B's canonical id (with all permissions).

When the bucket policy is empty, EC2 instances from account B are able to list the S3 bucket on account A.

The bucket is public and I want to grant access to specific public IPs and a specific VPC configured on account A.

This is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3_Bucket_Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_Number:role/EC2_Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc_id"
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "67.100.20.15/32",
                        "79.190.30.2/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can access the S3 bucket from the below IP addresses and the specified VPC however, I can't access the bucket from account B's EC2 instances.

The EC2 instances have the below assigned role with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Why can't I access the bucket in account A from account B?**

Comment: You have multiple statements in your bucket policy. One of them is a Deny. Deny trumps Allow. You'll need to modify the Deny statement so that it does not take effect when accessing the bucket from account B.

Comment: Alternatively, reorient the policy to simply allow the relevant S3 actions if coming from account A's VPC or specific IPs (and don't have any Deny clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have an explicit `Deny` statement in your S3 bucket policy, which is overriding the `Allow` statement so change your `Deny` statement to allow account B's role principal.**

---

This policy evaluation logic is highlighted in the [AWS Identity and Access Management
User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html):

[image]

In this case, you are falling into the first red block which will make the final decision a `Deny`.

---

Change your `StringNotEquals` to also check for the `aws:PrincipalArn` of account B's role so the policy doesn't deny account B's role anymore:

```
"Condition": {
    "StringNotLike": {
        "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc_id",
        "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_Number:role/EC2_Role"
    },
    "NotIpAddress": {
        "aws:SourceIp": [
            "67.100.20.15/32",
            "79.190.30.2/32"
        ]
    }
}
```

---

Full working example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3_Bucket_Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_Number:role/EC2_Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc_id",
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_Number:role/EC2_Role"
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "67.100.20.15/32",
                        "79.190.30.2/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find any condition named `NotPrencipal`, Do you mean to replace it with the `"Principal": "*"` ?

Comment: I get `Invalid policy syntax.`

Comment: @DaniWol. Ah - `You cannot use the NotPrincipal element in an IAM identity-based policy. ` - sorry! Answer should be fixed.